# Problem installing VLC on 12.04 - broken dependencies

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, dependencies, vlc

I am trying to install VLC on my Gateway netbook running 12.04 through wubi but whether I try using terminal or the software center I get this error message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libavcodec53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not going to be installed or
            libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
   Depends: libtar0 but it is not installable
   Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not installable
   Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not installable
   Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not installable
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have spent a good hour on google and the forums trying to resolve this but nothing seems to be working. I have tried using the daily releases ppa. I tried this...

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

...but it didn't change anything along with the other methods posted on the forums. I updated just before trying to download vlc but vlc would not download before the update either.

Any responses would be much appreciated.

**edit**
Here is the info you wanted.

```
vlc-data:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1
  Version table:
     2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
vlc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1
  Version table:
     2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe i386 Packages
 2.0.1-4 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
vlc-nox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1
  Version table:
     2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
libvlccore5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1
  Version table:
     2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages 
     2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
libvlc5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1
  Version table:
     2.0.8+git20130809+r605-0~r43~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages`
```

Comment: post the results of `apt-cache policy vlc-data vlc vlc-nox libvlccore5 libvlc5`

Comment: @doug output added by the way.